# Sorting a php array in a discontinus manner?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I don't know if I'm very clear in the title as English isn't my prime language,  but I'll try to make it clear...

I start with an array containing some 'ids' and some'values'.

What I need, is to organize the 'ids'  in a new array to be if possible apart when the 'values' they are associated with are alike.

So I came up with a solution, but if there is to much of a value type the spreading is uneven... So if one of you has a different, better, solution, I'm all ears open !

Thank you.

Here is what i came up with:

```
function discontinus_sort($to_sort, $order_by, $id){

while (count(array_count_values($to_sort)) >1) {

    $order[] = [$id => key($to_sort) , $order_by => $to_sort[key($to_sort)]];

    $holder = $to_sort[key($to_sort)];

    unset($to_sort[key($to_sort)]);

    reset($to_sort);

    if (isset($to_sort[key($to_sort)])) {

            while( $holder == $to_sort[key($to_sort)] ) {
            next($to_sort);
        }
    }
}

while ($to_sort) {

    $order[] = [$id => key($to_sort) , $order_by => $to_sort[key($to_sort)]];

    unset($to_sort[key($to_sort)]);

}
return $order;
}
```

and for an exemple :

```
$test= [0=>'red',1=>'red',2=>'red',3=>'crimson',4=>'aqua',5=>'chartreuse',6=>'green',7=>'chartreuse',8=>'red',9=>'crimson',10=>'crimson',11=>'aqua',12=>'aqua',13=>'green',14=>'crimson'];


$test_order = discontinus_sort($test, 'couleur', 'id');

foreach ($test_order as $key) { 

echo '<div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; margin:5px; float: left; background-     color:'.$key['couleur'].'; " ></div>';
}
```

if you change to many values let's say by red, you'll end up with a big stack of red at the end ...

Comment: You should use http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for this purpose

Comment: Umm so basically, you want the colors to be sorted based on their number in ascending order together?

Comment: No the opposite in fact, regardless the number ( the numbers are just the colors 'id'), but the colors need to be apart from each other not group

Comment: @xyzMaki So can be random colors every time but not next to each other? By the way, your code seems to be doing that pretty well, in which case did you _end up with a big stack of red at the end_?

Comment: Let's say you've got 10 red in your array, and 3 green. I'd like the 3 green to be evenly spread between the 10 red, as now the he first 6 colors would be alternated but the remaining 7 all red...